# Configure contact email in chrome web store

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I can't publish my chrome extension because it says "You must provide a contact email before you can publish any item."

I entered my E-Mail Address but it still does not work. Does anyone know how to configure that?

I published extensions successfully in the past, but apparently there was a policy change.

Here is the error message:

[image: error message]

And here the config i did:

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I faced same issue but it works after re-login.

Comment: I you have this problem and you don't have any solution, just up vote the question

Comment: Switching accounts away from and then going back to the account publishing the extension worked for me.

Comment: Yep that fixed "You must verify your contact email before you can publish any item. Begin the verification process on the Account tab." for me as well.  Despite it being verified.

Answer (score 58):

They overhauled their dashboard and this was hella confusing for me.

You need to click the header, and then account, and then you can find the email address here:
[image]

Comment: Yep there it is.  Yikes.  I had to logout and back in twice after this, then it worked...

Comment: It says 'tab' for each of the guidelines but the tabs are all over the place! This one, especially, is hiding behind the menu!!

Comment: Omg. Thank you so much. I was totally stuck.

Comment: Google once again shows that UI and User experience is not their strong point. Took me ages of trying to figure this out as there is an Account tab under user top right which is not the right "Account"

Comment: Holy cow this was driving me nuts - THANK YOU for explaining.

Comment: This saved my day. Thx a lot

Answer (score 2):

As aforementioned by [Haru](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14091757/haru) you'll need to re-login to fix it. To itemize, here is how you can fix it:

1. Head to your [Google Chrome Developer Dashboard](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/devconsole/)
2. On the top left, click on the collapsible menu (*three bars* icon)
3. Choose the second option: "account"
4. Under the heading "Profile" add your email.
5. On the top right, click on your profile picture.
6. A small screen will popup. Choose the option at the bottom: "logout"

Now when you login it will be working as expected.

Comment: Thanks for helping me navigate the 23 different hamburger menus to get this working. I was able to get this to work. However, after you've switched accounts and back (or signed out and back in), both of the "Save draft" and "Submit for review" buttons are enabled. Clicking "Save draft" will disable the "Submit for review" button and generate the error message again.